# How to loop over my Firebase snapshot to list using v-for?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, v-for

I want to filter data from my Firebase database to only list jobs with the *authUser* equal to the current signed in user.

I have utilized `.orderByChild` method to filter out the data. However, I cannot figure out why looping into the snapshot to get individual values does not work.

Here is my component where I want to list all jobs that meet this criteria.

[Jobs Component code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TIwn.png)

Also, if I do *console.log* to preview the data being received, it looks like this. Is this not okay?

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csViD.png)

Here is my Firebase data structure. There are no explicit rules defined.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhXUl.png)

I am fairly new to Vuejs.

After adding `self.myJobs = snapshot.val()`, my console output looks like this:

[updated console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWU7f.png)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try something like this ?

```js
let vm = this //define this variable before the cursor definition

// comment the snapshot.forEach section and replace by

vm.myJobs = snapshot.val() //or any variable containing the jobs
```

Comment: i have done this `self.myJobs = snapshot.val()` and tested using `console.log`. The output is updated in the question.

Comment: what do you get ?

Comment: Check that last image

Comment: I think it should be `this.myJobs = snapshot.val()`

Comment: using `this`  outputs an error on the console. This error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'myJobs' of null

Comment: use arrow functions then or try let vm = this before the cuser definition, then write vm.myJobs instead of this.myJobs

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Farouk Mekkaoui's answer, inside your v-for you need something like this:

```
  <li v-for="job in myJobs">
    {{ job.name }} //any or whatever property you want to access...
  </li>
```

EDIT:
Do not comment out snapshot.foreach loop.

```
snapshot.foreach(function(data){
  this.myJobs.push(data.val().name)
}
```

Comment: Tried that but no output on the browser. Just blank.

Comment: Edited my original answer.

Comment: @Farouk Mekkaoui`s last comment worked. I will make sure to test your method and give feedback. Thanks